# How should multiple environments be managed when using Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

**Background:**

I'm building an application where I want to use Azure AD B2C to enable consumer logins. When I have previously built applications in Azure, I would have a single "regular" Azure AD tenant, and a resource group for each environment (dev, test, prod, etc..).

I have now created an Azure AD B2C tenant for development purposes, following the guidelines here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/best-practices#operations which specify that I should create a tenant for each environment.

However, now my new B2C tenant shows up as a directory in the Azure portal, implying that I have also created a new directory.

**Question:**

What is the common wisdom regarding multiple B2C tenants? Should I create other dev resources in the same directory as my B2C tenant? Or should I just leave the new directory be, not interacting with it except when I need to configure my B2C tenant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directory = Tenant.
When you create a B2C tenant, it essentially is just a Directory. You connect dev apps to dev app registrations in the dev directory with dev users. Repeat for other envs. It is not treated like regular AAD, it is treated more like any other Azure Resource, eg a VM.